# Game Rec Reddit Experiment (in public beta).

Tags: discussion, game-recommendations, experiment

The reddit is **[gamerec](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamerec)**.

- **Posting guidelines.**

  - Only game-recs, please, and answers thereof.
- **Voting guidelines.**

  - When in doubt downvote.
- **Moderation guidelines.**

  - If you have 5k (?) rep here, you get to have mod there (get in touch.)
  - If a post isn't a game-rec written in English, remove it.
  - If a user is a jerk, ban him.

Comment: __Why not wait for the gamerec SE proper?__ Because I don't believe reputation can work for recommendations.

Comment: __Are you going to add a feed for it on the bridge?__ Yes -- maybe for the ticker, since Reddit is unlikely to onebox properly.

Comment: __What does reddit reput--- er, karma do?__ It's just for the bragging rights. [It doesn't actually unlock anything.](http://www.reddit.com/help/faq#WhatisthatnumbernexttousernamesAndwhatiskarma)

Comment: __Are delete and remove different?__ Yes, "remove" is the inverse of "approve", but there's no inverse for "delete".

Comment: RE moderation guidelines: What if someone asks for a short but engaging platforming game that has an awesome score system, and I respond with "むかしむかしあるところにとてつもなく仲の悪いツインテールの姉妹姫様がいらっしゃいましたとさ"? Does it really have to get removed? ♪

Comment: @grace it falls under 'answers thereof' does it not?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... I don't think using a third party website (and driving users away from here) is a good solution to our problem. I would much rather we find the solution ourselves -- be it with a good policy here, with the [Game Rec proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20517/game-recommendations?referrer=h7zt9WXAJu8N5QfMOt5KEg2), or adding a native fourth place to the SE network.

Good luck though, and please report back with feedback on how it worked out.

Comment: This is, of course, only my opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would drive users away. We shouldn't be hosting game recs. Reddit ahouldn't be hosting "real" questions. If anything else they would compliment each other -- see the standard SE reply to worries about new sites and splintering.